# customers cancel return products in my account page- Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders, sales-order, ecommerce-tracking

My requirement is adding **cancel** and **return** option in customer  account page.

1. add **cancel** option after place order.
2. add **return** option after delivered.

I am wondering it is a very essential option but magento does not provide default.

I hope someone handled the situation already.

Please share the hints or steps to achieve this in a proper magento way.

Comment: Have still looking for way?